# Handling flicks on object

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have created a new UIElement that derives from Systen.Windows.Controls.Canvas.

I am trying to handle flicks made on this object.

Everything is done in C#, in code (no XAML) using the Silverlight Phone Toolkit (February version as I want to target 7.0)

In my object constructor I do:

```
        //Create gesture handling
        gl = GestureService.GetGestureListener(this);
        gl.Flick += new EventHandler<FlickGestureEventArgs>(gl_Flick);
```

and gl_Flick is simply:

```
    void gl_Flick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.HorizontalVelocity >= 0)
        {
            // Right swipe (flick)
            if (gotSwipe != null)
            {
                gotSwipe(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, in the constructor, I also create and add a few TextBlocks

For some reason, the flick is only generating an event if done over one of those TextBocks. If I do the flick on any of the empty area of the Canvas nothing occurs.
As I can't find any documentations related to the Silverlight toolkit, everything has been done via trials&errors.

How could I do, so the flick will be recognised when performed anywhere over this canvas and not limited to over the children it contains?

Comment: Are there any other event handlers on the canvas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm more focused towards WPF, but the way you talk about it reminds me of the classic null background issue.

The solution: set a non null background for your canvas.

**EDIT**: something like

```
myCanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(1, 0, 0, 1));
```

Comment: It's the same problem for Windows Phone, he'll have to set the background to `Transparent` (or any other colour, but x:Null), to get touch-input on any FrameworkElement.

Comment: In WPF, Transparent can be tricky sometimes. I prefer to use something like #01000001

Comment: Works fine on Windows Phone :) `<Canvas Background="Transparent"></Canvas>`

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly the problem: adding this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent); fixed it.